# converting vb dnn module to c#, how?

Tags: dotnetnuke

i recently started working on DNN, i configured DNN at my machine with starter kit and other things 
require. I received a vb module from my client to work up on.
It's simple VB module, not dynamic module. I imported the module and i started working on it,
but i am more of c# coder, so i feel a bit uncomfortable working with this.
Could some body tell me how can i convert his module to c#, of is there any way that further coding i 
do in c#, i mean all my user control further i want to make in c# on that module.
Please guide me on it, or provide me some resources.

Comment: By vb you mean vb.net, I assume?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several tools out there for converting VB to C# - http://www.bing.com/search?setmkt=en-GB&q=convert+VB+to+c%23

However, if you want to work in C# and if it is a simple module, then you might be better off:

- install the DNN starter kit
- run the "new C# module" wizard
- using your VB module as a reference, recreate the functionality in the C# module
- enjoy coding forwards

For tutorials about working with DNN, there are lots of tutorials out there - and I particularly recommend Michael Washington's materials which he generally provides in both C# and VB - http://www.adefwebserver.com/DotNetNukeHELP/